# How to get and pass simultaneously a selected value from combo box to functions

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

I want to get the selected value from combobox and the same time I have to pass that value to other calling function, how to do this? the code which I wrote is insufficient to achieve this requirement, somebody please help me. I am familiar with SelectedIndexChanged in C# and other languages! is it similar available with Tkinter python?

```
def fill_Combo(self):
    combo1= ttk.Combobox(frame1,height=1, width=20)
    combo1['values'] = ("AA","BB","CC","DD","EE")
    combo1.current(0)
    combo1.pack()                  
    combo1.place(x=5, y = 75)
    var_Selected=combo1.current()
    combo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",select_Combo(var_Selected))


def select_Combo(self,var_Selected):
    print "The user selected value now is:"
    print  var_Selected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, `var_Selected` is always 0, because you set current to 0 when creating the combobox and only once set `var_Selected` to this value. What you have to do is get `combo1.current()` at the time `select_Combo` is executed. You can do this by renaming `combo1` to `self.combo1`, which is then automatically passed to `select_Combo` through self. Then you can get the current value and do anything you want with it.
And don't use both `pack` and `place`, pick one.

Example:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class app():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.fill_Combo()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def fill_Combo(self):
        self.combo1= ttk.Combobox(self.root,height=1, width=20)
        self.combo1['values'] = ("AA","BB","CC","DD","EE")
        self.combo1.current(0)              
        self.combo1.place(x=5, y = 75)
        self.combo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",self.select_Combo)

    def select_Combo(self, event):
        self.var_Selected = self.combo1.current()
        print "The user selected value now is:"
        print  self.var_Selected
        # Any other function you want to use as function(self.var_Selected) or a function that gets self

app()
```

Comment: It was a very helpful answer, really appreciate you well for your effort.